# Is there a way to autofill empty cells in R using a linear regression of the previous values for each subset of data?

Tags: r, database, linear-regression, autofill

I have a dataframe containing "Wood" data for each country for each year from 2000 to 2016, but missing values from 2017 to 2020:

| Country | Year | Wood |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Afghanistan | 2000 | 10789 |
| Afghanistan | 2001 | 11234 |
| Afghanistan | 2002 | 11567 |
| Afghanistan | 2003 | 12345 |
| Afghanistan | 2004 | 14321 |
| Afghanistan | 2016 | 15446 |
| Afghanistan | 2017 | na |
| Afghanistan | 2018 | na |
| Afghanistan | 2019 | na |
| Afghanistan | 2020 | na |
| Albania | 2000 | 3729 |
| Albania | 2000 | 7456 |

What I want to do is to automatically fill in the missing years of "Wood" data (2017/2018/2019/2020) with values extrapolated from a linear regression of the "Wood" data of the previous years (from 2000 to 2016) for each country (so Afghanistan will have it's own linear regression equation, Albania another, and so on, based on their increment/decrement).

Making things more tricky, for some countries data are not available, and they have only "NA" (I can't cancel the countries with only NA in "Df$Wood" as other columns with data are present in the dataframe). In this case, I do not want to autofill the empty cells.

I imagine I should set up some sort of loop performing the "ln" function for each country and auto-filling when "NA", but I am still pretty basic at R and can't really figure out how, especially given the tricky "empty country" issue.

Comment: Albania has 2 years 2000.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two ways that return the same results up to floating-point precision.

### 1 Use `Country` as a factor

The simplest way is to use the country as a regressor and fit one model only. Since there are countries without wood data, I will define a logical index with value `TRUE` only for countries with data. This will eliminate the others.

```
i <- as.logical(ave(df1$Wood, df1$Country, FUN = \(x) !all(is.na(x))))

fit <- lm(Wood ~ Year + Country, data = df1, na.action = na.exclude)
ypred <- predict(fit, newdata = df1[i & is.na(df1$Wood), ])
```

That's it.

### 2 Split the data by country and fit separate models.

If the data is split by country and a different model is fit to each subset, the predicted values are nearly the same. It just gives more work.

The logical index is once again used to keep only countries with wood data.

```
sp <- split(df1[i,], df1[i, "Country"])
ypred2_list <- lapply(sp, \(X){
  fit <- lm(Wood ~ Year, X, na.action = na.exclude)
  predict(fit, newdata = X[is.na(X$Wood), ])
})
```

### 3 Compare the results

Now see that the numeric results are not `identical` but that they are `all.equal`.

```
identical(ypred, unlist(unname(ypred2_list)))
#[1] FALSE
all.equal(ypred, unlist(unname(ypred2_list)))
#[1] TRUE
```

The differences are very small.

```
ypred - unlist(unname(ypred2_list))
#           7            8            9           10           27 
#1.164153e-10 1.164153e-10 2.328306e-10 1.164153e-10 1.873559e-10 
#          28           29           30           47           48 
#1.891749e-10 3.055902e-10 1.891749e-10 1.873559e-10 1.891749e-10 
#          49           50 
#3.055902e-10 1.891749e-10
```

### 4 Assign the results.

```
df1$Wood[i & is.na(df1$Wood)] <- ypred
```